# where should I save a file before open it

Tags: python-2.7

Where should I save a text file before I open it on python?
I tried to open a text file on the desktop, but that generated an error.

Comment: **Read a basic tutorial.** Basically the file can be almost anywhere, but you'll have to specify where it is relative to where you're running python.

Comment: What was the error? Always helps to provide specifics when asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: When you launch a python interpreter all file paths should be either relative to the path from which the interpreter was launched or should be absolute. I would suggest you try using the absolute path to the file. On Windows this will be `C:\Users\<your name>\Desktop\<file>` and on Linux systems should be `/home/<username>/Desktop/<file>`.

Comment: Using the path was worked,If my file name is "File1",Then can I open a file like that for write,                                                                                                               fob=open("File1","w")   ***Thnx for your help guys***